# Error when trying to create new SQL file in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

Whenever I try to create an SQL file, this error comes up:

```
Could not load type 'ManagedBatchParser.ICommandExecuter2' from assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The quick dirty way is to reinstall SQL Server.

Comment: That was going to be my next move, but I wanted to see if there's an easier fix before I go and do that.

Comment: sorry bro. I've gotten the exact same error verbatim, and I had to reinstall SQL Server Express on my workstation. It's a pain, but it fixed the problem

Comment: I've also read [uninstalling 2008 and installing 2008 R2](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/625399/vs-net-2010-crashes-when-opening-sql-file-from-windows-forms) also fixes the issue.